# PHP picture name from sql not loading

Tags: php, image, shopping-cart

I have a PHP shopping cart I am working on. I have all my pictures stored in a folder url directory of my project. In my SQL database I have an image table that holds all of the image names. When I load the picture names with my php It somehow adds some extra random characters to the directory path:
/img/%7B$row_product_image[name]%7D 404 (Not Found)
If I hardcode the image directory img/picturename.jpg It works.
Here is what I have.

```
<?php
include_once "objects/database.php";
include_once "objects/product.php";
include_once "objects/product_images.php";
// object instances
$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();
$product = new Product($db);
$product_image = new ProductImage($db);
$recordsPerPage = 1;
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    extract($row);
    echo '<div class="col-md-4 mb-2">';
        echo '<div class="product-id d-none">{$id}</div>';
            echo '<a href="product.php?id={$id}" class="product-link">';
                $product_image->product_id = $pid;
                $stmt_product_image = $product_image->readFirst();
                while($row_product_image = $stmt_product_image->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    echo '<div class="mb-1">';
                        echo '<img src="img/{$row_product_image[name]}" class="w-100" />';
                    echo '</div>';
                }
                echo '<div class="product-name mb-1">{$name}</div>';
            echo '</a>';

    echo '</div>';
}
class ProductImage {
    private $pdoConn;  private $table_name = "product_images";
    public $id;
    public $product_id;
    public $name;
    public $timestamp;
    public function __construct($dbconn) {
        $this->pdoConn = $dbconn;
    }
    function readFirst() {
        // SELECT query
        $query = "SELECT id, pid, name " .
                 "FROM " . $this->table_name . " " .
                 "WHERE pid = ? " .
                 "ORDER BY name DESC " .
                 "LIMIT 0, 1";
        // prepare query statement
        $stmt = $this->pdoConn->prepare($query);
        // sanitize
        $this->product_id=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->product_id));
        // bind variable as parameter
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $this->product_id);
        // execute query
        $stmt->execute();
        // return values
        return $stmt;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: %7B is the { and %7D is } from your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo '<img src="img/{$row_product_image[name]}" class="w-100" />';
```

PHP will NOT expand variables if string is quoted using single quotes ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single)). Also you need to quote "name" string to use it as array index ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)).

That said, either fix that by avoiding single quotes (but that's ugly, so don't):

```
echo "<img src=\"img/{$row_product_image['name']}\" class=\"w-100\" />";
```

or less painful to read:

```
echo '<img src="img/' . $row_product_image['name'] . '" class="w-100" />';
```

or even use `printf()` to avoid spaghetting the string:

```
printf('<img src="img/%s" class="w-100" />', $row_product_image['name']);
```

Comment: THANK YOU!! that did it I didnt know it was my quoting I understand why now

Answer (score 0):

Try this code: <?php while($product_rows=mysqli_fetch_array($query_run)){ ?> <div class="col-md-12"> <img src="img/<?php $product_rows['name']; ?>" class="img-responsive"?> <div?> <?php } ?>

Answer (score -1):

```
while($row_product_image = $stmt_product_image->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                echo '<div class="mb-1">';
                echo '<img src="img/'.$row_product_image['name'].'" class="w-100" />';
                echo '</div>';
            }
```

try it